# How to rename a key in JSON

Tags: json, node.js, xml, xml-parsing, converters

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:Order xmlns:p="http://no.lyse.ikt.altisalg.Order" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="filename.xsd" source="AltiSalg 2.4.4-IB-154-IB-154 (154)"><p:Customer><p:OrderId></p:OrderId>
<p:FirstName></p:FirstName>
<p:LastName></p:LastName>
<p:EmailAddress></p:EmailAddress>
<p:BirthDate></p:BirthDate>
<p:CellularPhone></p:CellularPhone>
<p:City></p:City>
<p:Country></p:Country>
<p:PostalCode></p:PostalCode>
<p:StreetAddress></p:StreetAddress>
<p:PartnerId></p:PartnerId>
<p:CommunicationPreferences><p:Phone></p:Phone>
<p:Email></p:Email>
<p:Mail></p:Mail>
<p:SMS></p:SMS>
</p:CommunicationPreferences>
<p:ServiceAgreement><p:AgreementType></p:AgreementType>
<p:AgreementStartDate></p:AgreementStartDate>
<p:AgreementStatus></p:AgreementStatus>
<p:Comment></p:Comment>
<p:ListOfAssets><p:Asset><p:ProductPartNumber></p:ProductPartNumber>
<p:Comments></p:Comments>
</p:Asset>
<p:Asset><p:ProductPartNumber></p:ProductPartNumber>
<p:Comments></p:Comments>
</p:Asset>
<p:Asset><p:ProductPartNumber></p:ProductPartNumber>
<p:Comments></p:Comments>
</p:Asset>
<p:Asset><p:ProductPartNumber></p:ProductPartNumber>
<p:Comments></p:Comments>
</p:Asset>
<p:Asset><p:ProductPartNumber></p:ProductPartNumber>
<p:Comments></p:Comments>
</p:Asset>
<p:Asset><p:ProductPartNumber></p:ProductPartNumber>
<p:Comments></p:Comments>
</p:Asset>
</p:ListOfAssets>
</p:ServiceAgreement>
</p:Customer>
</p:Order>
```

When i am trying to convert into xmltojson i got below screen shot keys. 
i need to remove **p:** from all keys. i am unable to access key because of p: is coming. When i am trying to check online converting its working and its not remove from my code. i am working on node and using **"xml-to-json-promise"** Module

https://prnt.sc/hvzrzf

Note : I can not any change in XML file.

Comment: A quick solution could be to just substitute any occurence of `"p:` with `"`. I would include the " in the capture to avoid removing text from actual content. Eg: `The ship: Lousiana`. Or one could even substitute in the source material. `<p:` replaced with `<`.

Answer (score 0):

`xml-to-json-promise` is based on the `xml2js` package (which itself is based on `sax-js`). I use `xml2js` and promisify it myself, but the trick is the `options.tagNameProcessors`. Read about them [in the docs](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#processing-attribute-tag-names-and-values)

Use it like this:

```
const prefixMatch = new RegExp(/(?!xmlns)^.*:/)
function stripPrefix(str) {
  return str.replace(prefixMatch, '');
}
convert.xmlDataToJSON(xml, {
  tagNameProcessors: [stripPrefix]
  // other options too
})
```

This is included in `xml2js` package and could be required like so:

```
const {stripPrefix} = require('xml2js/lib/processors')
```

Anyway, there ya go! Tag names are processed to rename the key (removing any prior prefix).